# Pushing over SSH to a GIT repository with Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, git, ssh

I am using Xcode 4.6 to develop my projects and I am using the local repository feature. However I would like to be able to push my repository to a remote ssh server.

I have tried the following but it did not work : 
I went to the organizer and then to my repository, I have then added a new remote with the following instructions : 
- Name : Just a name so I have put my project name
- Location : I have put a ssh path : user@domain:path_to_my_.git_folder

Then I have entered my ssh password, but there was no confirmation button though.

Once all this was done I returned to the development window and went to File->Source Control->Push but it says there is no remote found.

So I would like to know what should I do to make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: One of the rare questions that are tagged with "xcode" and **are actually** about Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the best solution for repo's on github and bitbucket is to create an SSH key-pair with no password.

```
$ cd .ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f github_id_rsa
$ vi config
```

Then add the following:

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa
```

And to then refer to the repo as:

```
ssh://github/trojanfoe/myrepo
      ^^^^^^
(note that's the name of the "Host" from the config file, not github.com)
```

This works well in Xcode, however I see "green lights" next to the repo during a *pull*, but "red lights" next to the repo during a *push* (this might be a bug in Xcode 5.1 beta), but it works without complaint and without the need for a password, which is great if you use Jenkins to do your release builds.

The Repositories under *Preferences* > *Accounts* cannot connect using the ssh alias either, but strangely they function just fine when performing Source Control operations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You address should look like this"
`ssh://git@git.urlOrLocal.com:2223/ios-app.git`
You don't need confirmation button. Also try not putting the password there. You'll be asked to enter it when you'll try to push.

Comment: here is what i did : ssh://git@myIP:2223/MYABSOLUTEPATH, i tried with the port 22 too and both of them gave me an infinite searching remote loop. But the ssh server was online

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your address. Try pinging it or \ and check your git config for username etc'

Comment: This is a bad solution.  Using an ssh key-pair with no password and setting up `.ssh/config` is much better.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Nice try, I didn't find the "setting up" button on my console... ^^ Could you please tell us *WHAT* should be set up *HOW*?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem with use ssh-agent, so :

`` eval `ssh-agent -c`       [start the ssh-agent]

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa     [enter your passphrase when you are prompted for it]

ssh-add -l                [lists out what keys are loaded in the agent] ``